# Tkinter refresh canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to create a line that follows my cursor. I don't want to have a trail from the previous frames.

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=720, height=720)

def mouseGetPos():
    global root
    relX = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
    relY = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
    return [relX, relY]

while True:
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_line(0,0, mouseGetPos()[0],mouseGetPos()[1])
    time.sleep(1/100)
    root.update()
```

How do I update/refresh my canvas? I'm using this for a game.

Comment: Don't use `while True` loops when using `tkinter`. Look at how to use `.bind("<Motion>", <function>)`. Also try `canvas.delete("all")` to clear the canvas.

Comment: @TheLizzard, there is no problem in using while true here. But I agree with you

Comment: @PCM Using a `while True` loop with a small `time.sleep` argument will increase the CPU usage of the computer. If you increase it the `time.sleep` too much, the GUI isn't going to behave properly. That is why `tkinter` has the `mainloop`. Also in this case it's easy to add useless things like `canvas.pack()` inside the loop when it's better if they are outside the loop.

Comment: canvas coordinates are produced like this `x = canvas.canvasx( ev.x ) y = canvas.canvasy( ev.y )` inside a bound function. I don't see the purpose of this code. Wouldn't it be better to draw lines anywhere on canvas?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to write a tkinter program is by using `mainloop` rather than creating your own gaming loop. That way you don't have to force any updates, the screen will be updated in the time between events automatically.

You can then bind a function to be called whenever the mouse moves. Each time tkinter detects the event, your function will be called.

Here's a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def drawLine(event):
    item_id = canvas.find_withtag("the_line")
    if item_id:
        canvas.coords("the_line", 0, 0, event.x, event.y)
    else:
        canvas.create_line(0, 0, event.x, event.y, tags=("the_line",))

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.bind("<Motion>", drawLine)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you use `canvas.create_line(-10, -10, -10, -10, tags=("the_line", ))` at the start, you wouldn't need the if statement or the `canvas.find_withtag("the_line")`. Assuming OP isn't scrolling their canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
while True:
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_line(0,0, mouseGetPos()[0],mouseGetPos()[1],tags='line')
    time.sleep(1/100),
    root.update()
    canvas.delete('line')
```

Make a tag - 'line', then delete that line so that you get desired results

Comment: That is still bad practise. Using events is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest solution that uses events. It's based off of @BryanOakley's answer

```py
import tkinter as tk

def draw_line(event:tk.Event) -> None:
    # Configure the lines' coordinates:
    canvas.coords("the_line", 0, 0, event.x, event.y)
    # event.x and event.y are the mouse's poition
        

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# Create a line that's going to be invisible.
canvas.create_line(-10, -10, -10, -10, tags=("the_line", ))

# Each time the mouse moves over the canvas call `draw_line`
canvas.bind("<Motion>", draw_line)

root.mainloop()
```